# First movie where you hear breathing in a helmet?

Tags: science-fiction, first-appearance, 2001-a-space-odyssey

Is *2001: A Space Odyssey* the first movie where you can [hear somebody's breathing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8N72t7aScY) in a helmet? I talk about Darth Vader's type of breathing; in the case of Kubrik's movie it is breathing in a space suit helmet, in Darth Vader's case in some life-support body suit's helmet.

I heard that this movie [space odyssey] is the first one where a machine rose against man. I think it is also the first film where you hear breathing in a helmet.

Comment: Well, be that as it may, Kubric embraced dialog-less screen time in this movie. There are many minutes where **ALL** we hear is the breathing. Including the whole beginning of time beginning of the movie, the actual script couldn't have been more than a very thin book.

Comment: Since you did not limit the question to space helmets explicitly, Thunderball (1965) starring Sean Connery, featured an extended diving scene, including a battle underwater. We heard the SCUBA breath sounds repeatedly....

Comment: Isnt this trivia?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander - mmm - I view trivia as more easily searchable stuff.  Yes, this *could* be trivia, but by that measure so could a lot of the site.  One could argue that this is a sound technique used to highlight their health (Vader), isolation, or exertion, or the environment that the character is in (space, underwater etc) - and an idea when this was first used might be of interest.